# MongoDb cursor style retrieval of embedded document property collection

Tags: .net, mongodb, nosql

Given the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id{get;set;}

    public List<MyOtherClass>{get;set;}
}
```

is it possible to retrieve and iterate the `List<MyOtherClass>` using a cursor so I don't have to load the entire document in one hit? Likewise, could I persist to the `List<MyOtherClass>` in the same fashion, i.e. create the MyClass document then persist new documents to the list in a loop?

Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way, maybe I need a different document/collection 'schema'?  If I were doing this in Sql I would have two tables and I would create the parent and all children in a transaction.  What I want to achieve is the same net effect.

Comment: regarding if you need one or two collections depends on the use case. You might create another question specifying your use case and you will get help for good schema patterns for that

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a subset of a document but not a cursor of a subset of a document. i.e. Array. More information regarding queries can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/